# How to access the Db instance from a secondary connection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

my server creates two connections to the mongoDB as following :

```
let mongoConnectionPrimary = mongoose.createConnection(envConfig.primaryConnectionURI, envConfig.primaryAuthCreds)

let mongoConnection = mongoose.connect(envConfig.connectionURI, envConfig.authCreds)
```

Basically connectionPrimary establishes connection to the admin database (which I will rarely use), and the other one establishes connection to the myDB databse (which I will mostly use).

I want to run the currentOp command, which according to the documentation is possible only on the admin database. For this I need to store the Db instance and then use .command to run the currentOp.

However, all articles I have found on the internet do the following :

```
let db = mongoose.connection.db
db.command({currentOp : 1})
```

This assumes that the default connection is to admin database, which is not so in my case. And I also can't change the default connection just for some operations which I will do rarely.

So my question is, how do I access the Db instance from the mongoConnectionPrimary connection?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you can use many databases (where you have access to) with the same connection string, ie connection string doesn't dictate you which database to use

Comment: @dododo Okay sure, but for design purposes I want to have a separate connection to the admin database. So how do I get the db instance? One thing I have read is that mongoose.connect returns a connection object and mongoose.createConnection also returns a connection object, but I am not able to do mongooseConnectionPrimary.db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I solved the issue and I am writing down the solution for anyone who might see this post in the future.

Basically, you can access the Db instance from the client object. So to access/change the Db instance from a secondary connection created using the createConnection method, just do the following :

```
const secondaryConn = mongoose.createConnection(connection_uri)
let db = secondaryConn.client.db("admin") //other db names work too
```

That's it, and then you can run the currentOp or other operations as required.